# Find an example which shows that the following inequality is sharp

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space.

In ([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0410492.pdf)) it was shown that for $A=(A_1,...,A_n) \in \mathcal{B}(E)^n$ we have,

$$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\|A\|\leq \omega(A) \leq \|A\|,$$
where
$$
\omega(A) = \sup_{\|x\|=1} \left(\sum_{k=1}^n |\langle A_kx,x\rangle|^2\right)^{1/2},
$$
and
$$\|A\|= \left\|\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^nA_k^*A_k \right\|^{1/2}.$$

> How can we prove that $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$ is optimal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The estimate $\omega_e(A) \leq \Vert A \Vert$ is sharp, as we can take $A=(Id, \dots, Id)$ and for this choice we get equality.

We now prove optimality under the additional assumption $\dim_\mathbb{C}(E)\geq n+1$. In case someone has some insight for lower dimension please let me know.

If we assume $\dim_\mathbb{C}(E)\geq n+1$, then it suffices to consider the case $E=\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ with the standard scalar product (otherwise choose a subspace of dimension $n+1$ and identify it with $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$). We choose $A_k: \mathbb{C}^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ such that
$$ A_k (x_1, \dots, x_{n+1})= (0, \dots,0 , x_1, 0, \dots, 0) $$
where $x_1$ is in the kth slot. The corresponding matrix consists of all zeros and a one in the kth row of the first column, e.g. for $n=3, k=2$
$$ A_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Now we set
$$ A=(A_2, \dots, A_{n+1} )$$
We have
$$ \Vert A_k x \Vert^2 = \langle (0, \dots, x_1, \dots, 0),(0, \dots, x_1, \dots, 0)\rangle = \vert x_1 \vert^2  $$
Thus, we get
$$ \Vert A \Vert = \sup_{\Vert x \Vert = 1} \sqrt{n} \vert x_1 \vert = \sqrt{n} $$
On the other hand we have
$$ \vert \langle A_k x, x \rangle \vert^2 = \vert \langle (0, \dots, x_1, \dots, 0), (x_1, \dots, x_{n+1}) \rangle \vert^2 = \vert x_1 \vert^2 \cdot \vert x_k \vert^2  $$
And hence, for $\Vert x \Vert=1$
$$ \left(\sum_{k=2}^{n+1} \vert \langle A_k x, x \rangle \vert^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}
= \left(\vert x_1 \vert^2 \cdot \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} \vert x_k \vert^2 \right)^\frac{1}{2}
= \left(\vert x_1 \vert^2 \cdot (1- \vert x_1 \vert^2)\right)^\frac{1}{2}
= \vert x_1 \vert \cdot \sqrt{1- \vert x_1 \vert^2}$$
Hence, we get
$$ \omega_e(A) = \sup_{\Vert x \Vert=1} \vert x_1 \vert \cdot \sqrt{1- \vert x_1 \vert^2} 
= \sup_{\vert x_1 \vert\leq 1} \vert x_1 \vert \cdot \sqrt{1- \vert x_1 \vert^2} 
= \frac{1}{2} $$
Thus, we finally get
$$ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}} \Vert A \Vert = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}} \cdot \sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{2} = \omega_e(A) $$

Comment: Dear Severin, the inequality is sharp. You can see :Roman Drnovšek & Vladimir Müller (2013): On joint numerical radius II, Linear
and Multilinear Algebra, DOI: 10.1080/03081087.2013.816303     (Theorem 9)

Comment: @Student Thanks for letting me know. I'll check it out, when I'll have some time. Maybe you want to include that reference in your question for future visitors?

Comment: Thank you. Yes I include this reference in the comment for the benifit of visitors.

Answer (score 2):

As stated, the example cannot be right. The three expressions in the inequality spit coefficients, so if $T/\sqrt n$ works, so does $T$.

Also the left inequalities is not sharp. For instance, if $E=\mathbb C$, then 
$$
\omega(A_1,\ldots,A_n)=\left\|\sum_{j=1}^n A_j^*A_j\right\|^{1/2}.
$$

Comment: Thank you Professor for your answer. However, please I don't understand why the left inequality cannot be sharp? The example taken in the paper is not correct. However, why we cannot find another example? By the way I think that the inequality
$$\omega(A_1,\cdots,A_n) \leq \left\|\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^nA_k^*A_k \right\|^{1/2}$$
  is sharp. Indeed, if one takes $A_k=S=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ for all $k$, we obtain equality in last inequality.

Comment: It's not about having equality in one case, but in all of them. The example I'm giving you is that when $\dim E=1$, your left inequality is always strict.

Comment: If I understand you, you mean by not ''sharp'' that is, it is impossible to find a same example $(A_1,\cdots,A_n)$ such that $$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\left\|\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^nA_k^*A_k \right\|^{1/2}= \omega(A_1,\cdots,A_n)=\left\|\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^nA_k^*A_k \right\|^{1/2}.$$  Please correct me if I made wrong. Thank you.

Comment: That's what I said. And the the case where $\dim E=1$ gives an example where that inequality is never sharp. But I don't know what happens when $\dim E\geq2$.

Comment: I'm puzzled. I don't see anything wrong with your computation.

Comment: If you look at (2.3) in Theorem 2.1, he says that the example of equality is given by the creation operators. I would guess than that should be the example then, and not the one given in your question. Just guessing.

Comment: Dear Professor, the inequality is sharp. You can see :Roman Drnovšek & Vladimir Müller (2013): On joint numerical radius II, Linear
and Multilinear Algebra, DOI: 10.1080/03081087.2013.816303     (Theorem 9)